# Microsoft PowerApp - OR function

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am struggling to use the OR function in my Powerapp

I have

```
SortByColumns(Filter(Scopes, StartsWith(Title, TextSearchBox1.Text)), "Title", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

and also

```
SortByColumns(Filter(Scopes, StartsWith(Title, BarcodeScanner1.Value)), "Title", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

But I want to combine it so it shows the value of the Barcodescanner 1 or the text box search

I tried

```
SortByColumns(Filter(Scopes, StartsWith(Title, OR(TextSearchBox1.Text,BarcodeScanner1.Value))), "Title", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

but this doesn't work...

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

The [Or function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-logicals) takes two logical (true/false) values as parameters, so you can try this expression:

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        Scopes,
        Or(
            StartsWith(Title, TextSearchBox1.Text),
            StartsWith(Title, BarcodeScanner1.Value))),
    "Title",
    If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using || condition to filter out , based on 2 different values from **Scopes**.

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        Scopes,
            StartsWith(Title, TextSearchBox1.Text) || StartsWith(Title, BarcodeScanner1.Value)
            ),
    "Title",
    If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

Comment: Code only answers are rarely useful. Please provide explanation.